# MAX6675 K-Thermocouple with Raspberry using python: always error value

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am using a [MAX6675](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/sensors/MAX6675.html) with a Raspberry and Python in my Project.

But I have a Problem that I cannot understand: when I am reading a value from the MAX6675. My Code is simple:

```
CLK=13
CS=6
DO=5
while True:
    max6675=MAX6675.MAX6675(CLK,CS,DO)
    print(max6675.readTempC())
    time.sleep(1)
```

I am using [this library here](https://github.com/tdack/MAX6675/blob/master/MAX6675/MAX6675.py).

At first, when I connect the Raspberry only with WiFi, receive the right value from the MAX6675. After that, when I connect the Raspberry Ethernet (at the same time eth0+wlan0 or only with eth0) and reading it, I get this error:

> The value is always 0.

Does Anyone know how this could happen?

[image: My code and value]

This Error happen, only when thermocouple has contact with heating plate, i want to measure. When i measure air Temperatur, error happen no more.

Answer (score 0):

After 3 Week i was able to find out what happen with my thermocouple. Error happen when i use LAN caple without electromagnetic shielding like this one:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlfC6.png

this Cable has Metal and somehow disturb my Sensor-Reading when connect with Raspberry. But i am not figure how this is Happening.

If anyone know About this and explain, thank so much.

Comment: It's illogical that using ethernet or using wifi would have any effect, unless of course you are not paying attention to power consumption and did not supply the pi with a 1.5A 5V source supply. Strange because I thought wifi would use more juice than the cat5.